# JQuery's AJAX request: what settings are required for retrieving JSON data?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to use JQuery's $.ajax request to retrieve some JSON data from a server. I read in JQuery's documentation that all their settings are optional which does not help me understand what I need or do not need. I am unsure what I need. Here is what I have:

**JS Code:**

```
function retrieve() {
     $.ajax({
        url : 'some_url',
        type : 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        contentType : 'application/json',
        data : JSON.stringify({
          key : 'value: ' 
        }),
        error : function(data) {
          console.log('error');
        },
        success : function(data) {
                    // callback function?
        }
     });
}
```

I want my .retrieve() method to be able to accept a function containing an array of everything on the server like so:

```
 SomeObject.retrieve(function(array){
       // do something w/ array
 }
```

**Question:** Do I need to omit or add any settings? How do I generate a callback function so that after the messages are downloaded I can use its data? Any replies will be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: The callback function is the success function. The one where you have the "// callback function ?" comment. You can pass a function to your retrieve method, and initialized the success field with this function. WHy don't you test your code, instead of asking if it will work?

Comment: @JB Nizet Thank you for the quick reply. How would I initialize the success field to create a callback function? Do I create a function in the 'success' setting?

Answer (score 2):

To execute something when the AJAX response has been successfully received (in the following example, showing the received data in an alert box):

```
function retrieve() {
    $.ajax({
        ...,
        success: function(data) {
            alert("Yes! AJAX worked. I received the following data: " + data);
        }
    });
}
```

To be able to pass a custom success callback function to your retrieve method:

```
function retrieve(successCallback) {
    $.ajax({
        ...,
        success: successCallback
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using JQuery's .get() and .post() is easier to understand.  Use .get() to retrieve data from your server like so:

```
$.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

This is going to get the information from test.html.  You need to know the url of where you're getting your data from.  This can be a controller on your server.  Then the function argument is what happens when it succeeds.  here it will populate the result elements html with your data and alert you that the load was performed.